# Why ASP.NET REMOTE_ADDR changed when used Windows7 as local host?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, windows-7

I have a web application that stores user IP address using REMOTE_ADDR which is working fine as I think.

When I was using XP with .net framework4 while testing, the App used to store 127.0.0.1 as remote address now on windows 7 it returns with "::1" and have no idea why. any one knows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Vista and later uses IPv6.

The IPv6 localhost address is `::1`.

Comment: oh really, and sure I don't have to change any thing or put IPv6 in my consideration when do similar work since I'm not dealing with it when run the APP online .. right?

Comment: Wrong.  The internet is in the process of moving to IPv6.

Comment: Thanks @Slaks .. will research then where I should start from .. thanks